# I have a variable inside the print function but the output is not leaving space

Tags: space

```
character_name = "Tom"

character_age = "50"

print("There once was a man named" +character_name+ ",")

print("he was" + character_age + "years old")


character_name = "Mike"


print("He really liked the name" + character_name + ",")

print("but didn't like being" + character_age +",")
```

**output**

There once was a man namedTom,

he was50years old

He really liked the nameMike,

but didn't like being50,

**How do I put space between named and Tom or was50years**

Answer (score 0):

character_name = "Tom"

character_age = "50"

print("There once was a man named " +character_name+ ",")

print(" he was " + character_age + " years old")

character_name = "Mike"

print("He really liked the name " + character_name + ",")

print("but didn't like being " + character_age +",")

Comment: It worked but I cant see the difference between this and my code

Comment: The difference is: at the 3rd line. This answer have a space `...was a man named[space]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
character_name = "Tom"

character_age = "50"

print("There once was a man named " +character_name+ ",")

print("he was " + character_age + " years old")

character_name = "Mike"

print("He really liked the name " + character_name + ",")

print("but didn't like being " + character_age +",")
```

Another way to solve this is to add `" "` between your print statements like this:

```
character_name = "Tom"

character_age = "50"

print("There once was a man named" + " " +character_name+ ",")

print("he was " + character_age + " " +  "years old")

character_name = "Mike"

print("He really liked the name"+ " " + character_name + ",")

print("but didn't like being" + " " + character_age +",")
```